# How to retrieve expanded_url entity form twitter json feed

Tags: php, json, twitter

need to get the expanded url from a tweet. Heres my incorrect code:

```
$twitter_data = json_decode($rss,true);
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
$iurlx = $twitter_data['results'][$i]['entities']['urls']['expanded_url'];
```

How to fix this as simply as possible?

Comment: Post code that you have. I thought twitter return data was an object.

Comment: added more of the code, but don't think anyone knows!

Comment: Can you post the data of `$twitter_data` ?